# Create a plain text message with Exchange 2013

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am trying to send a plain text message every time I create a message it changes to HTML format.

I am using PowerShell v5 with CDO 1.2.1 with Redemption v5.19 and connecting to Exchange 2013.

I am creating an IPM.Note and setting the bodyformat to 1 (plain text), however as soon as I add any text to the body the bodyformat value changes to 2 (HTML).  Once bodyformat is set to 2 I cannot change the value back.

```
$rs = New-Object -ComObject "Redemption.RDOSession"
$rsOutbox = $rs.GetDefaultFolder(4)
$msg = $rsOutbox.items.add("IPM.Note")
$msg.BodyFormat = 1
$msg.body = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the RTFBody instead to a string that explicitly specifies plain text body:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(4)
set Msg = folder.Items.Add
Msg.To = "user@example.com.com"
Msg.Subject = "testing body format"
Msg.RTFBody = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\fromtext \fbidis \deff0{\fonttbl " & _
"{\f0\fswiss Arial;}" & _
"{\f1\fmodern Courier New;}" & _
"{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}" & _
"{\f3\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier New;}}" & _
"{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}" & _
"\uc1\pard\plain\deftab360 \f0\fs20 Test \par" & _
"}"
Msg.BodyFormat = 1
Msg.Save
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this is caused by the limitation of using CDO and if I were to install Outlook my original code would work?

Comment: No, this has to do with what Outlook considers to be plain text vs RTF: it actually looks at the RTF body to make that determination.